# Find string and replace next word in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have file which has some lines.. e.g.

```
line no 20    # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off

line no 21         config.vm.box = "test_15_4"

line no 22    # The URL from where the 'config.vm.box' box will be fetched if it

line no 23    config.vm.box_url = "file:\\d:\\images\\test.box"
```

I have set a variable "replace = test_15_5".. and "Search = config.vm.box"

I need a batch code which will search "config.vm.box" in file and replace next string "test_15_4"  with %replace%.. Code should replace every occurrence in file.

I have written small code but not working out:

```
for /F "USEBACKQ delims=" %%j in ("%textfile%") do (

set row=%%j

IF "!row:config.vm.box=!"=="%%j" ( echo %%j>>"%outputFile%") ELSE ( echo %%j>>Nul  && ECHO config.vm.box = "%BoxName%">>"%outputFile%")
)
```

Comment: What environment are you using? Windows/Linux? This will determine the solution. Also, you will find more success on SO when you have some code to begin with.

Comment: Based on the `D:\images\test.box` and the [batch-file] tag, it's safe to say that this is Windows.

Comment: @GVashist, i have windows 7. Its windows batch file. i have created one batch file which is doing some cleanup activity. i am stuck over here. I have a input file which contain above lines, i need to replace specific thing in line after i found another string. Please guide.

Comment: your Code works fine for me, if: I add `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` (given, that all variables are defined properly). You can  remove `echo %%j>>Nul &&`

Answer (score 1):

The [syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) for replacing in batch-files: `%variable:StrToFind=NewStr%`

Your problem is a bit more complicated since you need double expansion. You can achieve it with the [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

Use `tokens=*` and not `delims=` in the [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) command since you don’t need to tokenize the line.

No need for `if`: If the search is found, it’s replaced, otherwise the original text is kept.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem set variables here: INPUT, OUTPUT, SEARCH, REPLACE

del %OUTPUT%

for /f "tokens=*" %%T in (%INPUT%) do (
  set PROCESSEDLINE=%%T
  >> %OUTPUT% echo !PROCESSEDLINE:%SEARCH%=%REPLACE%!
)
```

**UPDATE**

I tried the way with recreating the line with the search text.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%T in (%INPUT%) do (
  set PROCESSEDLINE=%%T
  if !PROCESSEDLINE!==!PROCESSEDLINE:%SEARCH%=! (
    rem not found
    >> %OUTPUT% echo !PROCESSEDLINE!
  ) else (
    rem found
    >> %OUTPUT% echo %SEARCH% %REPLACE%
  )
)
```

However, the simple replacing mechanism in batch-file interpreter will be totally confused with the search string containing special characters like space or `=`. In this case, I would prefer a more sophisticated tool to search and replace strings: [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed). It was ported to a standalone Windows application as a part of [UnxUtils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/).

With `sed`, the replacing command would be:

```
sed "s/config.vm.box = .*/config.vm.box = \"test_15_5\"/" < infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

It requires separate input and output files, just like my script above.

Comment: i did not get what "delete %output%" this will do.

i need to replace next word not the same word, so whether above thing will work?
As i understand it will replace the searched string, right?

Comment: The `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` files must be different since we are writing a whole new file. The command `echo` with the `>>` redirection appends to the `OUTPUT` and we must make it append to _nothing_ in the first iteration.

Comment: Replacing the next word does not make sense. What about the line 23 where the search string also appears? Wouldn’t it be easier to just recreate the line starting with `config.vm.box = `?

Comment: Updated the answer. I prefer to download and learn a specialized tool (which you could use in *nix environment too) than adjusting (maybe impossibly) a batch-file to each specific condition.

Comment: Not working.. :( i wrote the code same way as you said.. Problem is, it always goes to else  condition, if found or not found.
Did you try the code on your side. Copy lines which i have pasted in text file and run the program you gave..

Comment: Please read my answer to the end. The batch-code would work with limited kinds of input. Have you tried the `sed` option?